# UITableViewCells' labels with different heights alter labels' widths

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my UITableViewCells I am displaying text of varying lengths. To accomodate larger amounts of text and while also not requiring small texts amounts to be in huge table cells I am setting the height of the rows here...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    float padding = 40.0f;
    CGSize constraintSize;
    constraintSize.width = 320.0f - padding - padding;
    constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
    CGSize theSize = [thisrowstext sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] 
                            constrainedToSize:constraintSize 
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if(theSize.height < 24.0f) return 44.0f;
    else return theSize.height + 20.0f;
}
```

...it works well, unfortunately the textLabel's width seems to be affected too with some textLAbels (depending on row count) being pushed in a few pixels. I've tried setting indentation values, but that doesn't work. Has anyone else encountered this?

EDIT: I'm adding the layoutSubviews method of my UITableViewCell subclass that i'm using (no NIB).

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.hideImage)
    {
            self.imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
            self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-40.0f, 1.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f);
            CGRect frame = self.textLabel.frame;
            self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x - 40.0f, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width + 40.0f, frame.size.height);
            [self.textLabel setNeedsLayout];

    }
    else
    {
            self.imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
            self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(1.0f, 1.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f);        
            [self.textLabel setNeedsLayout];
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also adding cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *TableCellViewWithHidableImageIdentifier = @"TableCellViewWithHidableImage";
    TableCellViewWithHidableImage *cell = (TableCellViewWithHidableImage *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableCellViewWithHidableImageIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[TableCellViewWithHidableImage alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableCellViewWithHidableImageIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.hideImage = NO;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"empty.png"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"whatever";
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but it looks to me like it is the imageView on the left hand side of the cell. Seems like as the cell gets taller, it gets wider (trying to maintain aspect ratio?) and this is pushing your text to the right. What's odd is you image is not stretched. Might be worthwhile looking at what is happening to that image view during `layoutSubviews`. If your custom cell does not implement this method, maybe the base class' implementation is doing something you don't expect. You could override it and `NSLog` to the frame of the image view before and after the a call to `[super layoutSubviews]` to see whats going on.

Comment: I set the background of the cell to gray to see better what was going on. Looking more into the cell's layoutSubviews led me to the answer.  The textLabel was shrinking it's frame to the width needed for the text and then "floating" right. I couldn't figure out what property to change on the cell to make it "float" left so instead I manually set the frame's origin's x to 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing how you generate your table cells. Do you use a nib for your cells? I've found it much easier to use a nib for custom table cells, so try that if you aren't already.

I suspect you may have a problem with your autoresizeMask on one or more of your table cells' subviews.

Comment: That probably would help, please see above. Thanks! Rob